# How to dismantle a component after hiding it?

Tags: reactjs

When we return null from the render, the component is simply not displayed, but remains mounted.
Can I somehow not just hide the component, namely, dismantle it?
The option to explicitly unmount from the outside via ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode () does not fit.

```
class SuperComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    isShow: true
    };
}

onClose = () => this.setState({isShow: false});

render() {
    if (this.state.isShow === false) {
    return null;
}

return (<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <button type="button" onClick={this.onClose}>Close</button>
   </div>);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const Foo = () => {
  const [shouldShowBar, setShouldShowBar] = useState(true);

  const handleBarClose = useCallback(() => {
    setShouldShowBar(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {shouldShowBar && <Bar onClose={handleBarClose} />}
    </>
  );
};
```

If this is a simple modal window that should be shown on click and similar windows are planned to be used in many places, then for ease of use you can implement a wrapper that will use the render-props technique:

```
const Foo = ({ onConfirm }) => {
  return (
    <ModalWrapper
      onConfirm={onConfirm}
      body="Hello"
    >
      {showModal => (
        <Button onClick={showModal}>Show modal</Button>
      )}
    </ModalWrapper>
  );
}
```

This will allow not to produce in all components where one will be used, the logic of their state.